# Make post_content and other custom fields required

Tags: posts, validation, html5

What's the best way to set the `required` atribute on html forms in wordpress, for instance I would like post-content to be required, so this code need to be changed:

```
<textarea class="wp-editor-area" style="height: 300px; margin-top: 37px;" autocomplete="off" cols="40" name="content" id="content"></textarea>
```

To appear like this:

```
<textarea required class="wp-editor-area" style="height: 300px; margin-top: 37px;" autocomplete="off" cols="40" name="content" id="content"></textarea>
```

How can do it by a filter or action hook?
This same solution I will also use it for other fields in the publish post form.

What I want is to add the HTML5 `required` attribute on certain fields, once the page has been rendered.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_required.asp

Comment: You can achieve this by developing custom code like shared in this topic https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/101260/14347

Comment: I think the better and secure way is to use javascript code for "required"...

Comment: @Mukiikumar can you show me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have solved it as follows:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'my_admin_scripts') );

function my_admin_scripts($page) {
    global $post;

    if ($page == "post-new.php" OR $page == "post.php") {
        wp_register_script( 'my-custom-admin-scripts', plugins_url('/js/my-admin-post.js',dirname(__FILE__)), array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-sortable' ) , null, true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-custom-admin-scripts' );             
    }           
}
```

And put the required atribute by JQuery in the next js code (/js/my-admin-post.js):

```
// JavaScript Document
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#title').attr('required', true);
    $('#content').attr('required', true);
    $('#_my_custom_field').attr('required', true); 
});
```

Comment: For the editor area, when in Visual mode I get in the JS console `An invalid form control with name='content' is not focusable.` and no HTML5 tooltip pops out as warning indicating the field is required. However if I switch to the Text tab it works with no issue. Do you find a work around to this?

Answer (score 4):

Don't rely entirely on JavaScript validations. Use below hook for Server side validation.

```
function check_if_post_content_set( $maybe_empty, $postarr ) {
// Check if post is already created. IMPORTANT
if($postarr['ID'] && (int)$postarr['ID'] > 0){
    if( !$postarr['post_content'] OR $postarr['post_content'] == '' OR $postarr['post_content'] == NULL ){
        $maybe_empty = true;
    }
}
return $maybe_empty;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_empty_content', 'check_if_post_content_set', 999999, 2 );
```

Comment: This is fine to control that the field is not empty, but that already does HTML5 if we indicate the field as required.
What I want is to add an HTML5 attribute, once the page has been rendered

Comment: So you want to add some predefined content on new post if post_content is empty ?

Comment: No. What I want is to add the HTML5 `required` attribute on certain fields on the publish post form, once the page has been rendered, and before the user submit the form.

Comment: Just came across [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mandatory-fields/) .Fits your requirements.

Comment: this plugin hasn’t been updated in over 2 years and dosen't make what I want. I would like adding the HTML5 `required` atributte and make it as simple as possible